# Makeindex stops at scanning input file stdin

Tags: miktex, nomenclature

I'am trying to make a nomenclature in documentclass `mscThesis`, but when I try to use makeindex I can't go any further. Makeindex says:

> ```
> This is C:\Users\Rob van Vliet\Dropbox\Thesis\Thesis\makeindex.exe, version 2.15
> [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support).  
> Scanning input file stdin...
> ```

I've searched the internet and I've found many answers but it still doesn't go any further than this.

I've also tried `\makeglossary` but that doesn't work either.

I'm using `\usepackage{nomencl}`, I've put `\makenomenclature` in the preamble and I've put `\printnomenclature` in the place I want the nomenclature to be.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Give also a link to the source of `mscThesis`, please. And do not forget to add the command line options for MakeIndex – I guess that’s the real cause of your issue.

Comment: If `makeindex` is called without filename it tries to read from standard input, so try call `makeindex foo` if your `.tex` file is named `foo.tex`.

Comment: You can download the mscThesis class directly from here: http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/Education/MScTemplateLatex_new.zip\documentclass{mscThesis}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\makeindex

\begin{document}

%======================================Front Matter==================================
\frontmatter

\maketitle
\include{abstract}
\printnomenclature
\tocloflot

\include{preface}
\include{acknowledgements}
%\include{dedication}

%=====================================Main Matter===================================
\mainmatter

\nomenclature{$m$}{meter}

\end{document}